# How can I define a method where I need attributes from different classes?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, methods, attributes

I got a program from my professor where I had to do some tasks. Since we're currently learning "inheritance with classes", I'm not that good at it yet. We had been given a task where it says "Extend the output of mouse, screen and keyboard so that the user knows which computer in which room they belong to". I did this, but I'm not sure if it's true or if there is a better solution. Can anyone explain to me whether the whole thing can be solved better and if so, why? I have defined a method in each class where I get this as an output, but is there a better way where I only have to define a method once and this applies to all other classes? Thanks in advance

Here is my code:

```
class Room:
    __name = "unknown"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    
class Device:
    __name = "Device"

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def as_text(self):
        return "%s" % (self.__name)

class Computer(Device):
    __ip = "unknown"
    def __init__(self, name, ip, room):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__ip = ip
        self.__room = room

    def as_text(self):
        return "%s with ip=%s" % (super().as_text(), self.__ip)

class Laptop(Computer):
    def __init__(self, name, room, ip, with_case = True):
         super().__init__(name, room, ip)
         self.__with_case = with_case

    def as_text(self):
        if (self.__with_case):
            return "%s with case" % super().as_text()
        else:
            return super().as_text() 
   
class Screen(Device):
    __width = "1920"
    __height = "1080"
    def __init__(self, name, room, width, height, computer):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.__room = room
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height
        self.__computer = computer

    def as_text(self):
        return "%s with resolution %dx%d" % (super().as_text(), self.__width, self.__height)

    def screen_location_computer(self):
        return 'The screen with the height {} and width {} is located in Room {} and belongs to the computer {}'.format(self.__height, self.__width , self.__room.get_name(), self.__computer)

class Keyboard(Device):
    __language = 'English'
    def __init__(self, name, room, language, computer):
        super().__init__(name, room)
        self.__language = language
        self.__computer = computer

    def keyboard_location_computer(self):
        return 'The keyboard with the language {] is located in Room {} and belongs to the computer {}'.format(self.__language, self.__room.get_name(), self.__computer)    

class Mouse(Device):
    __type = 'Gaming Mouse'
    def __init__(self, name, room, type, computer):
        super().__init__(name, room)
        self.__type = type
        self.__computer = computer

    def mouse_location_computer(self):
        return 'The mouse with the type {] is located in Room {} and belongs to the computer {}'.format(self.__type, self.__room.get_name(), self.__computer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to regroup all common attributes and methods in the super class and leave only the specialized attributes in the subclasses, this way you can minimize the need of methods and arguments.

Idem for the method I renamed 'description' : one part is common to all instances (the end) while another (the beginning) is specific. Let super handle the common part and pass it the specialized part to assemble the whole string.

(I removed some classes and attributes for the simplicity of the example)

```
    class Device():
    __computer = None
    __name = None
    __room = None
    
    def __init__(self, name, computer, room):
        self.__name = name
        self.__computer = computer
        self.__room = room
    def room(self):
        return self.__room
    def name(self):
        return self.__name
    def description(self, str):
        return '{} is located in Room "{}" and belongs to the computer "{}"'.format(str, self.__room, self.__computer.name())
    

class Computer(Device):
    def __init__(self, name, room):
        super().__init__(name, self, room)

class Screen(Device):
    __width = "1920"
    __height = "1080"
    def __init__(self, name, computer, width, height):
        super().__init__(name, computer, computer.room())
        self.__width = width
        self.__height = height

    def description(self):
        return super().description('The screen with the height {} and width {}'.format(self.__height, self.__width))

class Mouse(Device):
    __type = 'Gaming Mouse'
    def __init__(self, name, computer, type):
        super().__init__(name, computer, computer.room())
        self.__type = type

    def description(self):
        return super().description('The mouse with the type {}'.format(self.__type))

cpt = Computer("Acer", "Classroom 12")
cpt2 = Computer("iMac 15", "Classroom 38")
screen = Screen("27 inch", cpt2, 1920, 1080)
mouse = Mouse("Mouse", cpt, "Gaming")

print (screen.description())
print (mouse.description())
```